# Delicious share count with new delicious url https://del.icio.us/

Tags: count, share, feed, delicious-api

Today I just noticed that the url of the delicious have been changed from https://delicious.com to https://del.icio.us/ due to which the URL I'm using is not working anymore.

```
$json_data = 'http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url=' . $url
```

Has anyone got the updated url to get the delicious URL share count?

I tried with

```
$json_data = 'http://feeds.del.icio.us/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url=' . $url
```

but it returns only `[]`

Comment: I found this project https://github.com/domainersuitedev/delicious-api which documents the 'api.del.icio.us/v1/*' api but I'm not aware of the 'feed.del.icio.us/v2' api.